# Arabic StackExchange [Re-Proposed]

Tags: discussion, arabic

بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

[We have a new proposal for an Arabic Language site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123866/arabic-language/123886#123886) This is the <s>third</s> <s>fourth</s> <s>fifth</s><s>sixth</s> seventh(?) proposal on Area51 for the Arabic Language, there could have been more.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Semitic Languages]

As far as I know, currently proposals are only allowed to stay One Year in each of the Definition and Commitment phases, and the reason for this is so that if there is enough interest the momentum keeps going, or else it gets closed. The proposal is currently 8 months in definition phase.

Now I would like to get this proposal successful, and Insha'Allah it should be so.  But I also think that more effort is needed from this community to get the proposal a success, why I think that is because:

1. Arabic is the language of Islam, and we get a number of questions on the subject, so when we get Arabic.SE up we could migrate the questions there
2. The success of Arabic.SE is key to building some of our policies here
3. Arabic.SE would contribute to this site's completeness as a counterpart
4. Arabic.SE would help in solving some minor issues we have here, and perhaps some major ones (I think).

And for those reasons, I would like to ask for this community to put ***a bit*** more efforts into the proposal for Arabic.SE to make it a success. [Here is a blog post on the proposal.](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/2014/07/ar-lang-proposal/)

Comment: The last proposal has been closed in commitment stage :(

Comment: Could you support the new proposal?