# Semitic languages StackExchange site

Tags: discussion, arabic

I'd just like to bring the following to your attention: some weeks ago I re-suggested a site for [Semitic languages on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117739/semitic-languages). The [immediate reason](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27200/72809) was the closing of the Hebrew proposal, however, I had been [pondering](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26678/72809) the idea for a while before. Basically, for both Hebrew and Arabic language sites have been proposed several times before but these proposals failed due to lack of interest (for Arabic, apparently at least [4 times](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1311/23995)). Additionally, there are smaller languages like Akkadian, Aramaic, Ge'ez, Maltese, etc., that are too small to ever get their own site. By combining these topics in one site for [Semitic languages](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117739/semitic-languages), I hope to create a greater user group and a sustainable site. I think the current example questions show that combining the topics is worthwhile, as several high-scoring example questions consider multiple Semitic languages.

So far, much of the interest has come from Hebrew-oriented people, for several reasons (closing of the Hebrew proposal; community ads on Christianity.SE and some advertisement on Judaism.SE and Hermeneutics.SE). I think that's a pity. I had hoped for a more or less even distribution of Arabic and Hebrew, since that way people from both target groups can be interested in the site. There is a risk that the site becomes too Hebrew-centred and that people interested in Arabic will not find the site that easily.

So, basically, I'd like to invite you all to come over to [Semitic languages](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117739/semitic-languages) and participate in the site's definition with questions about Arabic, Arabic dialects, interaction of Semitic languages, etc. It is perfectly fine to support both the [Arabic language proposal](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1311/23995) and the [Semitic language proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117739/semitic-languages). The goal is that at least one of them results in a sustainable site.

If you're interested, you're very welcome to support [Semitic languages](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117739/semitic-languages) in [the following ways](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

- Follow the proposal
- Post example questions
- Vote on example questions
- Create discussions to resolve unclarities / further specify scope

Thanks!

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Semitic Languages]

Answer (score -1):

My comment has become too long so let me post it as an answer:

I'm afraid even in a Semitic language site, the site will become too Hebrew-centered, as my personal experience is that Arabic people are too lazy and have only small pull and will leave the site if it doesn't graduate as soon as possible, they will waste time with fruitless debates and are rarely productive community builders this is basically what happened with the last beta.

And there could be a weird religious related moderation issue, especially if the Arabic community had a large orthodox Muslim close minded basis.

Beside the fact that you may only find a few native Arabic speakers who speak Hebrew and vice-versa for moderation as already mentioned in the answers and comments on your [former Area51 post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26678/is-there-interest-in-a-general-semitic-languages-site?noredirect=1&lq=1). So it would be challenging to build and moderate this community.

Of course I can see a big benefit if we could make it happen!

- As a site like that may last longer than any other.
- It might easier reach the commitment stage and we may reach all of that without pushing too much people whom will not sincerely or productively help building this site. And therefore leave it as soon as they might have done their "duty".

Good luck mate!

Comment: Down-voting is only constructive, when it is paired with a comment, else it is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with the new links!